# Is there any overhead when using ASGI based FastAPI for AWS Lambda?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, fastapi

Can you please advise, if there are any issues with using of FastAPI Web Framework in AWS Lambda:

- What framework capabilities will be lost if using in AWS Lambda
  environment?
- Is there any overhead associated with ASGI technology or
  anything else, e.g. when we have to use additional libraries like
  Magnum?

Answer (score 6):

We have been using the **API gateway -> AWS Lambda -> Mangum -> FastApi**  combo in production for 3-4 months now and have had no issues.

The restrictions come from the fact that Lambda is a sync request/reply setup.

- Less benefit from async ( async inside the request but not between requests).
  AWS lambda will create a container/python process for each request so while your code is `await`ing a call in a request it won't move on to the next request.
- No response streaming bodies.(use s3 for files etc)

The overhead is tiny, Mangum is super light ( see how little code is in: https://github.com/jordaneremieff/mangum/tree/main/mangum) its basically just restructuring the input dictionary.

Comment: Many thanks, Nath... 
ok I can understand "no async" when processing requests as Lambda handles a single request, but why not use async when you connect to the other aws resources or databases as a part of the request request processing?

Comment: yep you are correct,  You can't parallelize  processing of requests but  could use async  for parallelizing access to resources required to complete  a single request.

Comment: how about the logs? What method are u using to group logs from the endpoints?

Comment: for logs we are using the. https://awslabs.github.io/aws-lambda-powertools-python/2.15.0/core/logger/ library and setting the POWERTOOLS_SERVICE_NAME to group logs from various different lambdas.

Comment: That's not quite true of lambda. What is true is that the default python lambda runtimes provided by AWS all poll AWS lambda's backend for events API and invoke your handler in a synchronous loop. You could write your own runtime with an asynchronous event loop under the hood. Other runtimes (IE node, go) have asynchronous loops by default.

Comment: The runtime code itself is not "published" per-se... but the runtimes are published as docker images and the runtime source code is present on the images.

Comment: @Nath - I have an async use case. One of my FastAPI methods performs two independent network calls, let's say `data1` and `data2`; then it joins, performs some business logic and returns. Since these are I/O not CPU bound operations, I'd really like to know if I can *start* the data2 request while some server (not mine) is processing the data1 request. (All in the name of my service's latency.)

Comment: @jbuddy_13.  -  your case will work fine, just edited the answer to  try and make it clearer. let me know if I was sucessful!

Answer (score 3):

Short answer, not really. There is a tiny, tiny bit of overhead to translate the incoming event into an ASGI event and instantiate an ASGI-callable object(that's what frameworks like mangum do), but it is pretty negligable.

There are many good reasons to use FastAPI over something like flask or even just a basic lambda REST api. My biggest reason is the integration with pydantic `BaseModel`, it removes the need for lots of validation code.

Taking advantage of concurrency via an `async` handler function is not one of those advantages, at least in the default python lambda runtimes.

The main reason is that the runtime itself is essentially a ***SYNCHONOUS*** loop which polls their API for events and then invokes your handler.

The actual loop pulled directly from the AWS lambda runtime for python3.7 a few years ago:

```py
while True:
    event_request = lambda_runtime_client.wait_next_invocation()

    _GLOBAL_AWS_REQUEST_ID = event_request.invoke_id

    update_xray_env_variable(event_request.x_amzn_trace_id)

    handle_event_request(lambda_runtime_client,
                        request_handler,
                        event_request.invoke_id,
                        event_request.event_body,
                        event_request.content_type,
                        event_request.client_context,
                        event_request.cognito_identity,
                        event_request.invoked_function_arn,
                        event_request.deadline_time_in_ms,
                        log_sink)
```

Unless you write your own custom python runtime with an asynchronous event loop, making your handler function `async` will have zero effect because the above loop will not poll with `wait_next_invocation` until `handle_event_request` is complete. If another invocation requests comes into your function while it is not polling, AWS lambda will just spawn another concurrent execution for you instead.

I know that `Go` and `Node` default runtimes have an asynchronous base loop, so having an `async` handler is actually legit there. Others could too, I just don't know and it is not well documented.